# draw donut path using canvas element

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to draw a dounut path using canvas. It contains the inner and outer arch connecting with line. But I am getting wrongly canvas image. Please see the below image.

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

This is my code.

```
 this.ctx.beginPath();
 this.ctx.moveTo(options.x, options.y);
 this.ctx.arc(options.x, options.y, options.radius, options.start, options.end, false);
 this.ctx.lineTo(options.x, options.y);
 this.ctx.arc(options.x, options.y, options.innerR, options.start, options.end, false);
 this.ctx.closePath();
```

Anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Answer (score 0):

When moving your "pen" to (options.x, options.y) and then drawing a circle around this point, your "pen" first has to go to the starting position of your arc. Here the line is drawn that you don't want to have on your canvas.

To solve this problem, you have to calculate the starting position of your outer circle (depending on the start angle). You should try with sin or cos to calculate your "new" x and y.

It would then look something like

```
var newX = options.x + options.radius * cos(options.start);
var newY = options.y + options.radius * sin(options.start);
```

Then move to this position

```
this.ctx.moveTo(newX, newY);
```

And draw the circle around the old x and y

```
this.ctx.arc(options.x, options.y, options.radius, options.start, options.end, false);
```

For the inner circle and the end positions you can calculate it similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using css

```
        var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas.width, 0);
        gradient.addColorStop(0, "#008B8B");
        gradient.addColorStop(0.75, "#F5DEB3");
        ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Just remove the last two lines from my above code you will see that the inner circle appears again

[SEE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/uH5j9/)

Comment: If you have any problem. Just feel free to ask that too